# How to delete an Elasticsearch Index using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I have Python 2.7 and Elasticsearch 2.1.1. I used the following to delete an index:

```
es.delete(index='researchtest', doc_type='test')
```

but this gives me this message:

```
return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
TypeError: delete() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given)
```

I also tried this technique:

```
es.delete_by_query(
    index='researchtest', 
    doc_type='test',
    body='{"query":{"match_all":{}}}'
)
```

but I get this message:

```
AttributeError: 'Elasticsearch' object has no attribute 'delete_by_query'
```

Has the API changed for 2.1.1 for python?

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.delete

Answer (score 170, accepted):

For ES 8+ use:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

es.options(ignore_status=[400,404]).indices.delete(index='test-index')
```

For older versions use this notation:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

es.indices.delete(index='test-index', ignore=[400, 404])
```

Comment: is the ignore useful?

Comment: @LukAron it is if you are trying to delete a non existing index

Comment: This command returns a deprecation warning message for ElasticSearch python client 8+.
So, it's alternative for ES 8+ is:


```es.options(ignore_status=[400,404]).indices.delete(index='test-index')```

Answer (score 11):

If you have a document object (model) and you're using elasticsearch-dsl, specially with Python-3.X you can directly call the `delete` method of your model's `_index` attribute.

```
ClassName._index.delete()
```

Also as it's [stated in documentation](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html#document-life-cycle):

> The `_index` attribute is also home to the load_mappings method which will update the mapping on the Index from elasticsearch. This is very useful if you use dynamic mappings and want the class to be aware of those fields (for example if you wish the Date fields to be properly (de)serialized):
>
> ```
> Post._index.load_mappings()
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Since passing transport options in the API method is deprecated in the Elasticsearch python client 8+, the way to specify HTTP status codes that should be ignored (e.g. to prevent errors in case the target index does not exist) would be by using `Elasticsearch.options()` now:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

es.options(ignore_status=[400,404]).indices.delete(index='test-index')
```

(see  [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-elasticsearch)).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using elasticsearch-dsl, use

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Index

index = Index('test-index')
index.delete(ignore=[400, 404])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using old version ES 8+:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(http://localhost:9200)

# Delete
es.indices.delete(index='name_index', ignore=[400, 404])
```